# Exception occurred while flushing email queue: Connection could not be established with host localhost [Cannot assign requested address #99]

Tags: php, docker, swiftmailer, symfony4

My symfony 4 demo app can't send email with dev default swiftmailer configuration.
My app is in a php-fpm docker container 
my conf for swiftmailer is

```
MAILER_URL=smtp://localhost:25
```

Here is my log

```
[2017-12-17 15:48:43] php.DEBUG: Warning: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to localhost:25 (Cannot assign requested address) 

[2017-12-17 15:48:43] app.ERROR: Exception occurred while flushing email queue: Connection could not be established with host localhost [Cannot assign requested address #99] [] []
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: With gmail conf its works nicely, so I think that my problem is in docker container config

Answer (score 3):

I solve this by adding a mailcatcher container 
Add this to your docker-compose file

```
mailcatcher:
    image: yappabe/mailcatcher
    ports:
        - 1025:1025
        - 1080:1080
```

And then add your mailer url config

```
MAILER_URL=smtp://mailcatcher:1025
```

You can view the emails at yourdomain:1080

Comment: @winkbrace or just use the default mailcatcher image from symfony that comes by default when you install Mailer component. 

```php

mailcatcher:
    image: schickling/mailcatcher
    container_name: test_mailer
    ports:
      - "1080:1080"
      - "1025:1025"
```